# SwiftUI - Create static array from dictionary

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create an array with keys from a dictionary based on certain values from it. The dictionary that I have is *employees_main.json* and looks something like this:

```
{
 "John Doe": {
  "role": "Engineer",
  "location": "Europe",
  "isEmployedFullTime": true
 },
 "Jane Doe": {
  "role": "Manager",
  "location": "Europe",
  "isEmployedFullTime": true
 },
 "U.N. Owen": {
  "role": "Tech",
  "location": "Europe",
  "isEmployedFullTime": false
 }
}
```

To load it into Swift I have create a Struct in a file called Employee.swift, as well as a Bundle-Decodable.swift file, and it loaded correctly.

```
struct Employee: Codable {
    let role: String
    let location: String
    let isEmployedFullTime: Bool
}
```

Now in my ContentView I am trying to import the dictionary into an array of keys. My current code looks so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var employees = Bundle.main.decode("employees_main.json")
    var employees_names: [String] {
        employess.map(\.key)
    }
}
```

This works in creating an array of the keys, but the array is shuffled every time it is called, breaking code further down which assumes a static structure, e.g. employees_names[1] will always be "Jane Doe". The second thing is I want to only get the keys where isEmployedFullTime is set to true, however I am not sure on how that if statement would look like in this.

Comment: Regular Swift dictionaries are not ordered. You can use something like OrderedDictionary from Swift Collections, but it's probably a better plan to have a strategy to sort your data (by name, for example). In terms of filtering, you can add `.filter(\.isEmployedFullTime )` to an array of `Employee` or `.filter(\.value. isEmployedFullTime)` to a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, I will give filter a try. Now regarding the dictionary, since I can't make it ordered, why don't I instead turn it into an array? So instead of it being { <content> }, it will be {[ <content> ]}. This way it is an array of dictionaries and it will be ordered. Is this something that would be possible (accessible) by Swift? I come from a Python background so these things are a bit new to me.

Comment: Yes, that is a very reasonable approach.

Comment: Cool, I will give that a try, thank you for the help!